# Como não repetir termos no printf

Tags: c

Tenho outro problema. Minha atividade dessa vez é criar e ler os elementos de dois vetores, A e B, com 5 e 7 valores, respectivamente. Depois, o programa vai mostrar quais são os elementos que se repetem. Esse é o código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int a[5], b[7], i, j;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("Digite o %d elemento do vetor A: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for (j=0; j<7; j++) {
        printf("Digite o %d elemento do vetor B: ",j+1);
        scanf("%d",&b[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<7; j++) {
            if (a[i]==b[j]) {
                printf("O numero %d esta nos dois vetores\n",a[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Meu problema é, se em um dos vetores o valor for repetido, o programa imprime a informação duas vezes. Não é um erro, já que eu não coloquei uma condição, mas eu gostaria que mostrasse apenas uma vez.

Como acontece:

> a[0] = 5  No primeiro vetor eu coloquei termos iguais nos 2 primeiros elementos.
>
> a[1] = 5
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> b[0] = 5 No segundo, eu repeti o termo.
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .

Na hora de imprimir os repetidos, ele imprime a resposta duas vezes (já que ele checa pelo `a[0]b[0]` e depois pelo `a[1]b[0]`):

O número **5** está nos dois vetores. Tem algum jeito de mostrar que está nos dois vetores apenas uma vez?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode mudar os seus laços para verificar se não é um número repetido:

```c
// Percorre o vetor a.
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {

    // Percorre o vetor b.
    for (j=0; j<7; j++) {

        // Se o número está em ambos os vetores.
        if (a[i]==b[j]) {
            int repetido = 0; // Não é repetido até que se prove o contrário.

            // Percorre novamente os elementos já percorridos do vetor a para saber se não é repetido.
            for (k=0; k<i; k++) {

               // Se já está em uma posição anterior do vetor a, então é repetido.
               if (a[i]==a[k]) {
                   repetido = 1;
                   break; // Já sabe que é repetido, não precisa continuar procurando.
               }
            }

            // Só mostra a mensagem se não for repetido.
            if (!repetido) printf("O numero %d esta nos dois vetores\n",a[i]);

            // Interrompe o laço que itera o vetor b, pois já sabe que está em ambos os vetores, não precisa continuar procurando.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira alternativa de resolver esse problema, de forma mais eficiente, é primeiro ordenar os dois vetores e depois fazer um "merge", similar ao que você faria no mergesort.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[5] = { 110, 2, 99, 99, 106 },
        b[7] = { 2, 7, 8, 9, 110, 99 },
        i = 0, j = 0, N99 = 0;
    char numrepet[5] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++){//Com esses loops colocamos os numeros repetidos em numrepet[]

            if (a[i] == b[j]){
                if (a[i] == 110){//coloco um 'c' porque 110 é o valor do 'n' você vai entender lá em baixo
                    numrepet[i] = 'c';
                    break;
                }
                else if (a[i] == 99 && !N99){//99 é o valor do 'c' usado ali em cima tive que tratar esse caso também.
                    N99 = 1;
                    printf("O numero 99 esta nos dois vetores\n", a[i]);
                }
                else {
                    numrepet[i] = a[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        for (j = i+1; j < 5; j++){//Com esses loops comparamos numrepet[i] com os demais elementos

            if (numrepet[i] == numrepet[j]){
                numrepet[j] = 'n';//tira números repetidos e coloca 'n' que será o nosso null
                //Exemplo numrepet[] {'1', '1', '2', '2'} transforma-se em numrepet[] {'1', 'n', '2', 'n'}
            }

        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        if (numrepet[i] != 'n' && numrepet[i] != NULL){
            printf("O numero %d esta nos dois vetores\n", a[i]);
        }

    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Se quiser ver a saída: [código](http://codepad.org/9XJMntci)

Obs.: Não funciona com alguns números muito grandes, mas acho que não usará números grandes nesta aplicação e em muitas outras, mas por segurança é melhor barrar esses números grandes, mas isso deixarei para você.

Comment: Tentei com `int a[5] = { 110, 2, 99, 5, 106 }, b[7] = { 2, 7, 8, 9, 110, 99 }`. O resultado foi que ele encontrou os números 110 e 2 nos vetores, mas não achou o 99. http://ideone.com/stueRn O motivo é que o caractere 'c' tem o código 99, mas ele já achou o 110 antes.

Comment: @Victor Agora que pude mudar, então criei um caso especifico para o 99 também.

Answer (score 0):

O segredo é a criação de um vetor `x` capaz de mapear as repetições e até mesmo a frequência delas.

1) Solução - Mapeamento da repetição dos valores do vetor `a` no vetor `b`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INT_MAX_VALUE  (100)

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int a[5] = { 1, 1, 3, 3, 6 };
    int b[7] = { 1, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
    int x[INT_MAX_VALUE]; 

    int i;
    int j;

    /* Inicializa os itens do mapa com valor 0 */
    for( i = 0; i < INT_MAX_VALUE; i++ )
        x[i] = 0;

    /* Mapeamento de repeticoes */
    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < 7; j++ )
        {
            if( a[i] == b[j] )
            {
                x[ a[i] ] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Exibe somente os valores repetidos */
    for( i = 0; i < INT_MAX_VALUE; i++ )
        if( x[i] )
            printf("O valor %d contido no vetor A, se repete no vetor B.\n", i );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Compilando (no Linux):

```
$ gcc -Wall vetores.c -o vetores
```

Testando:

```
$ ./vetores
O valor 1 contido no vetor A, se repete no vetor B.
O valor 3 contido no vetor A, se repete no vetor B.
```

2) Mapeamento da frequência de repetição dos elementos do vetor `a` no vetor `b`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int b[7] = { 1, 3, 5, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
    int x[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 

    int i;
    int j;

    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        for( j = 0; j < 7; j++ )
            if( a[i] == b[j] )
                x[i]++;

    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        if( x[i] > 0 )
            printf("O numero %d se repete %d veze(s) no vetor b.\n", a[i], x[i] );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Compilando (no Linux):

```
$ gcc -Wall vetores.c -o vetores
```

Testando:

```
$ ./vetores
O numero 1 se repete 1 veze(s) no vetor b.
O numero 3 se repete 1 veze(s) no vetor b.
O numero 5 se repete 2 veze(s) no vetor b.
```

Espero que ajude!